# Is it possable to invert the image output on a computer for a rear projection screen?

Tags: video, graphics-card

Is there a way to flip/invert/mirror a video out on a computer with a on board Intel video card? I'm making a large rear projection screen and i need to invert the image to project properly. One of my projectors has a function that automatically inverts the image, but the other one may or may not (likely not) and i need two projectors to drive the system so I'm hoping to do the inversion on the computer side before projecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look under your video card settings. Under Windows, Intel video card drivers usually have a system tray icon with a name of something like "graphical preferences". Under this, you can select the screen orientation and such.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux:

```
xrandr -x
```

To undo:

```
xrandr -o normal
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, use a screen rotation utility, such as [iRotate](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/irotate.shtm).

Your video driver must have the required capacity for this (but most now do).

[image]

Comment: Dose this program support inverting/mirroring? I don't need to rotate the screen, i need to mirror it so that when it projects from the rear it shows up properly at the front. This is very different from simply rotating it.

Comment: @Faken: Video drivers as a rule don't support mirroring, and I didn't manage to find such a software product.

Comment: @harrymc: Ahh, thats unfortunate, maybe i will need to physically mirror it with an actual mirror. Thanks anyways.